# My glTF export from Unreal Engine is not opening in Blender

Tags: export, unreal-engine

I optimized my file in Unreal Engine then I exported the .glb file (glTF binary) of the whole scene to Blender but some meshes are not opening in Blender and showing an error in the log.

[image]